# Strip ALL html from title

Tags: php, html

I need to strip the html that is generated out of this title:

```
<h3><?php echo $feed->itemTitle; ?></h3>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A statement of a problem isn't asking a question; where did you get stuck? What help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in PHP function [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: just as long as you expect the content to be 'valid' html

Comment: So something like this?
<h3><?php echo strip_tags($feed->itemTitle); ?></h3>

Here's an example of the outputted title right now:

Tech battle with &#39;<b>patent</b> trolls&#39;

I want all the html stripped out leaving a nice, clean title.